# G select with enum value

Tags: select, grails, enums

In my Domain i declared an enum and then i declared my class

```
package myApp

import java.util.Date;
// Sex for Male Female end Other
enum Sex {M,F,O}
```

Now i need to crate a g:select that contains all the possible value of the sex enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<g:select name="sex" from="${myApp.Sex.values()}"/>
```